# Adding data attribute value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

I am trying to add a data attribute with a value to a li, but for some reason its not working. 
Iv done this before on divs but for some reason its not working correctly now.

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/76MDE/1/

Here is my code.

```
<ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
        <h1><a href="#">cool</a></h1>
    </li>
</ul>

$('.name').data("element", "name");
```

Comment: working.. http://jsfiddle.net/76MDE/4/

Comment: It's working exactly as expected, jQuery's `data()` stores data in an internal object, it does not set attributes, that would be `attr()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.data()` does not add the `data-*` attribute. It creates a jQuery object and it will be stored internally in a jQuery cache variable.

If you want to set the attribute you must use `.attr()`

```
$('.name').attr("data-element", "name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$('.name').attr("data-element", "name");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/76MDE/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/76MDE/5/)

USE THIS

```
$('.name').attr("data", "element");
```

Comment: Actually it has to be `$('.name').attr("data-element", "name");`

Comment: Question asked is to "add a data attribute with a value to a li".. Wat else i can add in this...

Answer (score 0):

It IS working, as you can verify by putting a:

```
alert($('.name').data("element"));
```

It's only that the HTML is not modified.

If you want to see it in the HTML, too, use the following:

```
$('.name').attr("data-element", "name");
```